# wrong argument value is passed

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
public class decimalToBinary {

    static String reversedBin="";
    static String binS = "";

    static String rawBinary(int x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            return binS = binS + "";
        }

        return binS = binS + x%2 +rawBinary(x / 2);
    }

    static String reverse(String x, int y) {
        if(y==0) {
            return reversedBin = reversedBin+ x.charAt(0);
        }
        return reversedBin = reversedBin + x.charAt(y) + reverse(x,y-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int d = 100;     
        int x=rawBinary(d).length()-1;
        System.out.println(reverse( rawBinary(d) , rawBinary(d).length()-1 ));
        
    }
}
```

Here variable x(in main) value is 6 which is correct but when i write the same thing in system.out.println ==> (rawBinary(d).length()-1) it gives value 510 which is incorrrect.
I know i cant just put x in system.out.println rather than rawBinary(d).length()-1.
But i want to know the reason why it gives the error.

When I tried putting x in the print statement, it just worked fine. But i want to know the reason why it gives the error.

error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 510 out of bounds for length 63
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkIndex(String.java:4570)
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:46)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1527)
        at decimalToBinary.reverse(decimalToBinary.java:18)
        at decimalToBinary.main(decimalToBinary.java:25)
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the code you wrote? I see what your code is doing, I'm trying to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Note that your `rawBinary` method appears to depend on previous results - it's very unclear what it's attempting to do or why. (Ditto `reverse`.)

Comment: rawBinary method converts decimal to binary (unreversed) and reverse method just reverse the value to get correct binary value.

Comment: `main`-->`rawBinary`-->`reverse`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable `String binS = ""` inside the `rawBinary` function.

Using `static String binS = ""` Causes the previous values created using the function `rawBinary` to be saved.